# Apply HOG+SVM Training to Webcam for Object Detection

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I have trained my SVM classifier by extracting HOG features from a positive and negative dataset

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import cv2
import numpy as np

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()


def hoggify(x,z):

    data=[]

    for i in range(1,int(z)):
        image = cv2.imread("/Users/munirmalik/cvprojek/cod/"+x+"/"+"file"+str(i)+".jpg", 0)
        dim = 128
        img = cv2.resize(image, (dim,dim), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        img = hog.compute(img)
        img = np.squeeze(img)
        data.append(img)

    return data

def svmClassify(features,labels):
    clf=SVC(C=10000,kernel="linear",gamma=0.000001)
    clf.fit(features,labels)

    return clf

def list_to_matrix(lst):
    return np.stack(lst)
```

I want to apply that training so that the program will be able to detect my custom object (chairs).

I have added labels to each set already; what needs to be done next?

Comment: Are you using scikit-learn's Support Vector Classification module?  This code cannot run on its own.  Mainly, you haven't shown what packages you have included.

Comment: @rayryeng Apologies, I've included them in the edit. Would I have to use the SVM function from opencv?

Comment: No you don't have to use it from OpenCV.  I asked that because it'll allow me to write an answer :P

Comment: @rayryeng Haha so how do I proceed from here?

Comment: I'm already writing an answer.  Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have three of the most important pieces available at your disposal.  `hoggify` creates a list of HOG descriptors - one for each image.  Note that the expected input for computing the descriptor is a grayscale image and the descriptor is returned as a 2D array with 1 column which means that each element in the HOG descriptor has its own row.  However, you are using `np.squeeze` to remove the singleton column and replacing it with a 1D numpy array instead, so we're fine here.  You would then use `list_to_matrix` to convert the list into a `numpy` array.  Once you do this, you can use `svmClassify` to finally train your data.  This assumes that you already have your `labels` in a 1D `numpy` array.  After you train your SVM, you would use the [`SVC.predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict) method where given input HOG features, it would classify whether the image belonged to a chair or not.

Therefore, the steps you need to do are:

1. Use `hoggify` to create your list of HOG descriptors, one per image.  It looks like the input `x` is a prefix to whatever you called your chair images as, while `z` denotes the total number of images you want to load in.  Remember that `range` is exclusive of the ending value, so you may want to add a `+ 1` after `int(z)` (i.e. `int(z) + 1`) to ensure that you include the end.  I'm not sure if this is the case, but I wanted to throw it out there.

   ```
   x = '...' # Whatever prefix you called your chairs
   z = 100 # Load in 100 images for example
   lst = hoggify(x, z)
   ```
2. Convert the list of HOG descriptors into an actual matrix:

   ```
   data = list_to_matrix(lst)
   ```
3. Train your SVM classifier.  Assuming you already have your labels stored in `labels` where a value `0` denotes not a chair and `1` denotes a chair and it is a 1D `numpy` array:

   ```
   labels = ... # Define labels here as a numpy array
   clf = svmClassify(data, labels)
   ```
4. Use your SVM classifer to perform predictions.  Assuming you have a test image you want to test with your classifier, you will need to do the same processing steps like you did with your training data.  I'm assuming that's what `hoggify` does where you can specify a different `x` to denote different sets to use.  Specify a new variable `xtest` to specify this different directory or prefix, as well as the number of images you need, then use `hoggify` combined with `list_to_matrix` to get your features:

   ```
   xtest = '...' # Define new test prefix here
   ztest = 50 # 50 test images
   lst_test = hoggify(xtest, ztest)
   test_data = list_to_matrix(lst_test)
   pred = clf.predict(test_data)
   ```

   `pred` will contain an array of predicted labels, one for each test image that you have.  If you want, you can see how well your SVM did with the training data, so since you have this already at your disposal, just use `data` again from step #2:

   ```
   pred_training = clf.predict(data)
   ```

   `pred_training` will contain an array of predicted labels, one for each training image.

---

If you ultimately want to use this with a webcam, the process would be to use a [`VideoCapture`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) object and specify the ID of the device that is connected to your computer.  Usually there's only one webcam connected to your computer, so use the ID of 0.  Once you do this, the process would be to use a loop, grab a frame, convert it to grayscale as HOG descriptors require a grayscale image, compute the descriptor, then classify the image.

Something like this would work, assuming that you've already trained your model and you've created a HOG descriptor object from before:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
dim = 128 # For HOG

while True:
    # Capture the frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Show the image on the screen
    cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Convert the image into a HOG descriptor
    gray = cv2.resize(gray, (dim, dim), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    features = hog.compute(gray)
    features = features.T # Transpose so that the feature is in a single row

    # Predict the label
    pred = clf.predict(features)

    # Show the label on the screen
    print("The label of the image is: " + str(pred))

    # Pause for 25 ms and keep going until you push q on the keyboard
    if cv2.waitKey(25) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release() # Release the camera resource
cv2.destroyAllWindows() # Close the image window
```

The above process reads in an image, displays it on the screen, converts the image into grayscale so we can compute its HOG descriptor, ensures that the data is in a single row compatible for the SVM you trained and we then predict its label.  We print this to the screen, and we wait for 25 ms before we read in the next frame so we don't overload your CPU.  Also, you can quit the program at any time by pushing the <kbd>q</kbd> key on your keyboard.  Otherwise, this program will loop forever.  Once we finish, we release the camera resource back to the computer so that it can be made available for other processes.

Comment: Thanks!! but what if I want to test it via my webcam? i.e. detect the chairs through my live webcam feed?

Comment: No problem at all. This was a fun exercise. Good luck!